How to find the place where there are problems with TCP, TCPOFOQueue?
In my project I use NATS JetStream, I use publish to stream rps request, this means that the client will wait for a response from the server, but often there is a timeout error, what the problem is, it is not clear.
I started collecting metrics with node_exporter and viewing them in grafana. in the TCP Errors panel you can see a lot of errors with the following description: TCPOFOQueue - TCP layer receives an out of order packet and has enough memory to queue it
Grafana graph
Moreover, these errors coincide in time with the errors that occur in my application.
Can you please tell me where to dig to find out and fix this problem?
I send usual request via python client for nats and receive exception nats: timeout
await connection.request(
    message=b"some_message",
    subject="order.cancel",
    timeout=1
)

I think problem not with Nats Server or VPS because I have redeployed, problem still happening. Before reinstalling VPS I try to connect to Nats Server from my local PC and send requests, sometimes I receive timeouts :) BUT after reinstalling VPS I try to do same thing and don't receive timeouts and don't see errors in grafana graph (I make ~100 rpc) Аfter this we can conclude that the problem is not in nats-py (I thought that sending a large number of messages at the same time is accompanied by a bug in the implementation of nats for python) Now I'm even more confused, wtf.

If you have more details to add, edit the question, don't put them in comments.
